# Swift - How to encode a more than 512 character string?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, nsuserdefaults

In my App I want to store a array of my custom class `UserSavedTextElement`. This works pretty well but when I want so store a string which contains more than 512 characters, the app crushes with the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My custom class:

```
import Foundation


class UserSavedTextElement: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {

static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

   func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
       aCoder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
       aCoder.encode(text, forKey: "text")
   }

   var title: String
   var text: String

   init(newTitle: String, newText: String){
       self.title = newTitle
       self.text = newText
   }

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       self.title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as! String
       self.text = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "text") as! String
   }

}
```

To save the array I use:

```
    do{
        let textData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: textArray, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(textData, forKey: "spokenTextHistory")
        print("saved")
    }catch{
        print("not saved")
    }
```

Also when the String contains more than 512 Characters is prints: "saved"

My code to load the array(`AppDelegate` - `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`):

```
    let textData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "spokenTextHistory") as? NSData

    if let textData = textData {
        do{
            let textDataArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, UserSavedTextElement.self], from: textData as Data) as? [UserSavedTextElement]
            if let textDataArray1 = textDataArray {
                textArray = textDataArray1
            }
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

It crushes on this line:

```
self.text = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "text") as! String
```

The array in which the data should be saved is declared like this:

```
var textArray:[UserSavedTextElement] = []
```

If it`s important: The string which should be saved is coming from a UITextView

How can I save more than 512 characters?

Comment: I tried your code with Strings of 1000 and 2000 characters, and no crash. Maybe some other parts of your code, currently not shown, is affecting the result. Are you sure you have shown exactly the same code in your project?

Comment: Yes, it‘s exactly the same code, but the string is from a UITextView. Is it possible that this causes the error?

Comment: It`s that way:
var textArray:[UserSavedTextElement] = []

I can add UserSavedTextElement-Elements to it without problems, and it works fine. But when I close the app and reopen again and the textArray should be filled again, it crushes.

Comment: No I tested it myself. I added charakters until it crushed....

Comment: Sorry my English is not the best. Do you mean I should load the data in ViewDidLoad ?

Comment: Maybe it`s my fault, because I never worked with breakpoints, but even when I set the breakpoint on the last Bracket (after the crush line!!!!) it don`t crushes....

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/akfms7neyvj3lgt/Screenshot%202018-10-13%2019.37.55.png?dl=0]

Comment: But why the error is shown in this line?

Comment: Sorry, I have noticed that the error is in this line.... Because of the first element in the Array (with less than 512 characters) it crashed not and it reached not the "dangerous" element....

Comment: Anyway: Thanks for your help!